# Could not establish secure channel for ssl/tls authority

Tags: wcf, ssl, client

WCF service installed on two servers and accessing that service through load balancer. We have domain validation certificate which is installed on load balancer. WCF client is giving error "Could not establish secure channel for ssl/tls authority" while adding service reference but SOAPUI is able to access service.

I am not sure what is causing this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is the account running the WCF client application failed to access the private key of the client certificate.
The reason we should establish the secure channel for SSL authority is that the communication between the server-side and the client-side works over https, therefore, these two sides should exchange the public key of the certificate. After that, the private key of the client certificate will be used to unencrypt the https message so that the https traffic would work properly. Likewise, the server account also should have access to the private key of the service certificate.
Please refer to the below steps to add the Everyone account to the management group of the private key of the client certificate so that the client account can access the private key properly.
[image]

---

[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.